# Calling stored procedure in EF with Complex Data Type

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, complex-data-types

I am new to working with `Entity Framework` in a sample `ASP.NET/MVC 3.0 VS2010` project. I have imported two stored procedures as Function Imports and, in doing so, created a complex data type for each.

I am trying to run the following c# code:

```
public ComplexDataType RunStoredProc()
{
    var context = new DbEntities();
    int param1 = 370;
    int param2 = -1;
    string param3 = "Current";

    ComplexDataType result = new ComplexDataType;
    result = context.StoredProc(param1, param2, param3);
    return result;
}
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert data type 
    System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult(ComplexDataType) to 'ComplexDataType'
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly store the results of the stored proc in a complex data type?

Comment: show your mapping and StoredProc method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DbSet.SqlQuery` method to get results from a stored procedure.

```
int param1=12;
int param2=53;
var results=context.ComplexDataTypes.SqlQuery.
                       ("dbo.YourSPNameHere @p0 @p1", param1,param2).Single();
```

Assuming you have a collection like this defined your DbContext class.

```
public DbSet<ComplexDataType> ComplexDataTypes { set;get;}
```

More information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592907).

Comment: The project isn't recognizing context.Database.SqlQuery, but it gives me an option for context.ExecuteStoreQuery; following your syntax above with the same command, it's giving me the same error -- can not implicitly convert. Any other ideas?

Comment: which version of entity framework you are using ? is your stored proc returning something back ?

Comment: Using EF 4.0; stored proc returns about 10 columns and usually between 5 and 15 rows

Comment: Well, let me be clear -- the stored proc ends in a SELECT statement that outputs that data, though the query itself does not contain an explicit "return" clause. Although if that is an issue I don't think that would be related to the complex data type. The complex data type, when set up in VS2010, does recognize all expected columns, and I can call them from an instantiated complex data type result set ("result") in the OP; just can't write anything into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try and change this:

```
result = context.StoredProc(param1, param2, param3);
```

to this:

```
result = (ComplexDataType) context.StoredProc(param1, param2, param3);
```

Comment: Same error here; it won't let me cast as the complex data type. Still displays same error as above. Any other ideas?